# Using available physical CPU core in pthread in Linux

Tags: c, pthreads, cpu-usage

I am using Linux Centos.

I am coding in c with pthread and using **pthread_set_affinity**.I want to see each thread to run in unique processor.Like---

```
thread1 in proccessor 0
thread2 in proccessor 1
.
.
.
threadn in processor n
```

currently when i use this set_affinity it runs but when i saw the System-monitor i see that CPU utilization of eight core is not distributed.

CODE is like that
::

```
        if(for thread 1 )
        { 
        pthread_attr_init(&pta);
        CPU_SET(0,&cpuset);
        pthread_setaffinity_np(thread1, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
        pthread_create(&thread1,&pta,&sendimsg,(void*)&message);
        pthread_join(thread1,NULL);
        printf("User for Thread One : %d\n",numb.fir);
        pthread_attr_destroy(&pta);
        CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
        }  

            else if(for thread 2)
            {
            pthread_attr_init(&pra);
            CPU_SET(1,&cpuset1);
            pthread_setaffinity_np(thread2, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
            pthread_create(&thread2,&pra,&sendimsg,(void*)&message);
            pthread_join(thread2,NULL);
            printf("User for Thread Two : %d\n",numb.sec);
            pthread_attr_destroy(&pra);
            CPU_ZERO(&cpuset1);
            }  

            for eight thread that way.
```

Note : thread are assigned distributedly like 20 20 20 20 ...20

the percentage is like that way

10%  1% 0% 2% 0% 1% 0% 0% 1%

I have eight core pc and trying to run 8 thread in 8 core.Is there a way to completly utilize 8 core in this pthread and pthread_set_affinity.

Comment: May be some threads are cpu intensive and some threads are sleeping or waiting for mutex lock, waiting on blocked IO calls.

Comment: Maybe you could show some code, then somebody might help with something more than generalizing assumptions.

Comment: If the threads is using common data between them, this might not be such a good idea actually, since then that data has to be copied between caches instead of being all in just one cache.

Comment: Joachim Pileborg @ They are not using common data.Every thread use different databut same method with mutex.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have enough work to use the threads completely. You shouldn't need to set the affinity to do this, just spawn off 8 threads that can actually 100% utilize a single thread.